# C/C++ pointer type pointing to single bit?

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I want to modify individual bits of data, (for e.g. `int`s or `char`s). I want to do this by making a pointer, say `ptr`. by assigning it to some int or char, and then after incrementing `ptr` n times, I want to access the nth bit of that data.
    Something like

```
// If i want to change all the 8 bits in a char variable
char c="A";
T *ptr=&c; //T is the data type of pointer I want..
int index=0;
for(index;index<8;index++)
{
    *ptr=1;  //Something like assigning 1 to the bit pointed by ptr...
}
```

Comment: Use bitwise operations to modify bits.

Comment: Maybe `std::bitset` - http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/

Comment: The distance a pointer gets incremented is measured in bytes *not* bits.

Comment: This code does not compile since `char c="A";` is invalid.

Comment: Or a `vector<bool>::iterator`?

Answer (score 7):

There no such thing as a bit pointer in C++. You need to use two things, a byte pointer and an offset to the bit. That seems to be what you are getting towards in your code. Here's how you do the individual bit operations.

```
// set a bit
*ptr |= 1 << index;

// clear a bit
*ptr &= ~(1 << index);

// test a bit
if (*ptr & (1 << index))
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible to have address of individual bit, but you can utilize structures with bit fields. Like in this example from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field) so:

```
struct box_props
{
     unsigned int opaque       : 1;
     unsigned int fill_color   : 3;
     unsigned int              : 4; // fill to 8 bits
     unsigned int show_border  : 1;
     unsigned int border_color : 3;
     unsigned int border_style : 2;
     unsigned int              : 2; // fill to 16 bits
};
```

Then by manipulating individual fields you will change sets of bits inside `unsigned int`. Technically this is identical to bitwise operations, but in this case compiler will generate the code (and you have lower chances of bug).

Be advised that you have to be cautious using bit fields.

Answer (score 1):

The smallest addressable memory unit in C and C++ is 1 byte. So You cannot have a pointer to anything less than a byte.If you want to perform bitwise operations C and C++ provide the **[bitwise operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C)** for these operations.

Comment: maybe you can point him towards using the `std::bitset` also?

Answer (score 1):

C and C++ doesn't have a "bit pointer", technically speaking, C and C++ as such, deosn't know about "bits". You could build your own type, to do this, you need two things: A pointer to some type (`char`, `int` - probably unsigned) and a bit number. You'd then use the pointer and the bit number, along with the bitwise operators, to actually access the values.

Comment: C and C++ [do know about bits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field), but you cannot obtain pointers to them. There have been [proposals for first-class bitfields](ftp://www.moscoso.org/pub/computing/museum/esr/first-class-bitfields.html), but they never took off.

Comment: This answer addresses the OPs question. An iterator on bits is certainly possible, but there is nothing built-in.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing like a pointer to a bit

If you want all bits set to 1 then `c = 0xff;` is what you want, if you want to set a bit under some condition:

```
for(index;index<8;index++)
{
    if (condition) c |= 1 << index;
}
```

As you can see there is no need to use a pointer

Answer (score 0):

You can not read a single bit from the memory, CPU always read a full cache line, which could have different sizes for different CPUs.

But from the language point of view you can use bit fields

- http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter6/bitfields.html
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field